# How to calculate a d path in SVG?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, c3.js

[image]trying to set path svg corners.

yet didn't succeed to set bottom corners rounded,

code of path element:

```
          path = 'M ' + points[0][indexX] + ',' + (points[0][indexY] - 7) + ' ' +
            'L' + points[1][indexX] + ',' + (points[1][indexY] + bar_radius) + ' ' +
            'Q' + points[1][indexX] + ',' + points[1][indexY] + ' ' + (points[1][indexX] + bar_radius) + ',' + points[1][indexY] + ' ' +
            'L' + (points[2][indexX] - bar_radius) + ',' + points[2][indexY] + ' ' +
            'Q' + points[2][indexX] + ',' + points[2][indexY] + ' ' + points[2][indexX] + ',' + (points[2][indexY] + bar_radius) + ' ' +
            'L' + points[3][indexX] + ',' + (points[3][indexY] - 7) + ' ' +
            'z';
```

```
d="M 44.2,291 L44.2,261.42857142857144 Q44.2,259.42857142857144 46.2,259.42857142857144 L57.800000000000004,259.42857142857144 Q59.800000000000004,259.42857142857144 59.800000000000004,261.42857142857144 L59.800000000000004,291 z"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to actually draw curves on the bottom of those bars. Unless you have specific reasons for wanting to do so, that's probably not the way you'd like to achieve the desired look.

As it turns out, you can actually specify a corner-radius for rectangle objects. When approached this way, your task becomes entirely trivial. You no longer specify each and every vertex, but just a position, size and corner-radius.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-1 -1 40 40" >
    <rect
       style="opacity:1;fill:#0000ff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="rect4189"
       width="15.5"
       height="31.5"
       x="0"
       y="0"
       rx="2"
       ry="2" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided much information, but I am going to assume that `points[0..3]` are in the order: top-left, bottom-left, bottom-right, top-right. That is what it looks like to me.

I think your mistake was that you may have forgotten that Y increases downwards. Some of the signs in your path formula were wrong.

- The `+ bar_radius` in the second line should be `- bar_radius`.
- The `+ bar_radius` in the fifth line should be `- bar_radius`.

```js
const indexX = 0, indexY = 1;
const bar_radius = 10;

const points = [[30, 10],
                [30, 190],
                [70, 190],
                [70, 10]];

const bar = document.getElementById("bar");

path = 'M ' + points[0][indexX] + ',' + (points[0][indexY] - 7) + ' ' +
        'L' + points[1][indexX] + ',' + (points[1][indexY] - bar_radius) + ' ' +
        'Q' + points[1][indexX] + ',' + points[1][indexY] + ' ' + (points[1][indexX] + bar_radius) + ',' + points[1][indexY] + ' ' +
        'L' + (points[2][indexX] - bar_radius) + ',' + points[2][indexY] + ' ' +
        'Q' + points[2][indexX] + ',' + points[2][indexY] + ' ' + points[2][indexX] + ',' + (points[2][indexY] - bar_radius) + ' ' +
        'L' + points[3][indexX] + ',' + (points[3][indexY] - 7) + ' ' +
        'z';
        
bar.setAttribute("d", path);
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="200">
  <path id="bar" d="" fill="rebeccapurple"/>
</svg>
```